# iOS: Switching between views programmatically

Tags: ios

I am currently working on an app and I would like to know if there is a way to programmatically switch between views? I have looked up lots of videos on youtube and forums on google but every time people claim that they are doing it programmatically, they are still using the storyboard to do some of the view switching. Is there a way to switch between views without using the storyboards at all (just using pure code)?  I really dislike using the interface builder and would like to switch between views only programmatically if that's possible.

If you are familiar with Android development, I would like to know if there is something along the lines of the Intent class for iOS development.

Comment: Totally. I've written large complicated apps with no storyboard. Just manipulate your view controllers entirely programmatically.

Comment: See my answer here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831287/how-to-switch-between-views-on-ios/25446347#25446347

Answer (score 0):

I'm familiar with Android and you are confusing iOS terms. First of all, in Android you are using an `Intent` basically to start a new `Activity`. In iOS you can say that `UIViewController` is the equivalent of `Activity`, so for switching between `UIViewController`s you can use `addChildViewController / removeFromParentViewController` if you have nested `UIViewController`s (methods found on `UIViewController`).

Now if you want to create a stack of `UIViewController`s something like Android's back stack and provide a back button or back navigation, `UINavigationController` with the popular `push/popViewController:animated:`.

Also, as an observation, everything you see in `Storyboards` can be done programatically, except the segue between controllers, you can't drag segue programatically :)).

Now, you know that it can be done programatically, but I strongly advise you to use `Storyboards` as much as possible, if you want to learn iOS and see what's under the hood then yes, you might want to do some stuff programatically before starting to use storyboards, but after that, please use them, storyboards are your friend, you will easily find UI bugs, your code won't be crowded with UI code, the app structure will be more intuitive for you and other people who might work on the project, easy way to create UI.

All I can say, I wish Android would have such a tool (I know it already has one but it's a crap compared with IB) so that I can create UI for android too.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean **view controller** you can simply created your view controller programmatically and push or present the new viewController from your actual view controller (`self`). If you have a `navigationController`:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

or otherwise for example:

```
[self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

you can also choose the transition style before present the new view controller:

```
[secondViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

you have few type of transitions:

```
UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical
UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal
UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve
UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl
```

What else? :)

Answer (score 0):

this is exactly what you are looking for, the static method of UIView

```
+ (void)transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

> Creates a transition animation between the specified views using the given parameters.